# Return yaml value to puppet fact lookup

Tags: puppet, hiera, yaml

I'm trying to resolve a YAML value in a module

```
file { '/boot/config.txt' :
ensure      => present,
mode        => '0755',
content => $::hostname?{
     'serverName1.domain' => template('template1'),
     default => template('template2'),
     }
}
```

above with hardcoded names works nicely, however I'm trying to something like this:

```
file { '/boot/config.txt' :
ensure      => present,
mode        => '0755',
content => $::hostname?{
     <%= scope.call_function('hiera',['server_name_in_hiera']) %> => template('template1'),
     default => template('template2'),
     }
}
```

I'm sure its doable and I'm just doing something stupid.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Figured it:

```
file { '/boot/config.txt' :
ensure      => present,
mode        => '0755',
content => $::hostname?{
     hiera('server_name_in_hiera') => template('template1'),
     default => template('template2'),
     }
}
```